# Combining IF statement to this Max LOD calc?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a line graph of 12 months. Overlaid, I have a dual axis setup to show circles during each month to make it pop out more.

Something I'm trying to attempt is showing which dept has the max sales for that month.

For example, Month of March has $50k in sales, shown by the first line mark. In the second (circle mark) axis, I want to display a LOD calc to show the department who contributed to the most sales for the whole company, and then the circle will correspond to a color, which can be deciphered by a color legend.

Here is what I have, but I know I need to place an if statement within the max function, I can't seem to figure that part out.

`{fixed:max({fixed[Department]:sum([Sales])})}`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly if using FIXED, by the sound of what you're doing, you should also fix for the month as well as department.

```
{fixed[Department],Month[DateField]:sum([Sales])}
```

Then it may be as simple as something like:

```
IF SUM([Sales]) = MAX({fixed[Department],Month[DateField]:sum([Sales])}) THEN [Department] END
```

Although I have a nasty feeling that may be too simplistic and you have to look at table calculations instead. Give it a shot and see how you get on without the table calcs.